# If Statements in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax-error

I have a block of code that checks to see if all my inputs on the form have a value selected, but it seems to generate constant errors, and I can't see the issue. Here's the code:

```
<?php
if($_POST['name'] != ""){
    if($_POST['degree'] != ""){
        if($_POST['grades'] != ""){
            if($_POST['values'] != ""){
                if((($_POST['values1'] != "") and ($_POST['values2'] != "")) or (($_POST['values1'] != "") and ($_POST['values3'] != "")) or (($_POST['values2'] != "") and ($_POST['values3'] != ""))){
{$_POST['name'] = "";
$_POST['degree'] = "";
$_POST['grades'] = "";
$_POST['values1'] = "":
$_POST['values2'] = "":
$_POST['values3'] = "":
$_POST['thoughts'] = "":}}}}}}
?>
```

Comment: I'm astounded over and over... This can't be real.

Comment: @Shahar [It's not the worst we've seen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21417199/250259) (must be a 10k user to see it)

Comment: Are you a beginner in PHP? If you're, you're learning a bad habit

Comment: If you have code that generates errors and you can't find them easily, it is probability time to refactor (rewrite).

Comment: @JohnConde Even ignoring that atrocity at the top... HE'S SETTING ALL THE POST VARIABLES TO "". WHAT'S THE POINT OF SENDING THE DATA THEN?

Comment: @Shahar I could only guess at what they're attempting to do. Not gonna say it is brilliant.

Comment: @shahar I honestly feel what you are saying here... But I doubt saying this stuff is going to help the OP much, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, but I'm brand new to PHP, and I don't think you need to be so critical. I've been writing for about a week and a half.

Comment: Also @shahar, I wasn't done. I was just trying to get it to work, I'd get it to output all of it into a file. No point in adding excess complexity when I'm just trying to figure it out...

Comment: @user3019274 Don't worry I didn't downvote you.

Comment: But are you having any other problems?

Comment: @shahar After reviewing the question, yeah, some pretty obvious errors, sorry for the dumb post, I just didn't see it, and spent a while banging my head on the table (figuratively)

Comment: @shahar I'm not having errors, I'm just trying to figure out my way around PHP. Is there a method in which I can change the background color of a form element (textarea, radio buttons)?

Comment: @user3019274 You're going to use HTML/CSS to do that.

Comment: @shahar I know that (As hard as it may be to believe, I do know HTML and CSS decently well), but what I'm trying to do is check the inputs, and if the values are not present, the section is highlighted in red (I know Javascript is far easier, but my project stipulated PHP)

Comment: @user3019274 See, PHP is a *server*-sided scripting language. You can't just change it like that (unless you reload the page).

Comment: @shahar it is. The submit button calls the page (php function at the top)

Comment: @user3019274 Probably the easiest way is to use JavaScript, honestly.

Comment: That what I figured (and did), but my prof said that's no good for the scope of the assignment (The course is in server side scripting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You end several statements with colons instead of semi-colons:

```
$_POST['values1'] = "": <-- HERE
$_POST['values2'] = "": <-- HERE
$_POST['values3'] = "": <-- HERE
```

PHP error messages surely told you that.

Comment: Well, the errors, @shahar, would seem to be from that. The rest...

Comment: I can't seem to get it to output errors. I'm running it on MAMP, and I went into the php.ini file and set it to output errors, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

-> You can reduce all those statements to 'and' statements, using `&&`:

```
if($_POST['name'] != ""){
    if($_POST['degree'] != ""){
        if($_POST['grades'] != ""){
            if($_POST['values'] != ""){
                //etc
//Will be:
if($_POST['name'] != "" && $_POST['degree'] != "" && /*etc. */){
```

-> You should check `isset($_POST['a'])` before you check the value of `$_POST['a']`.

-> What do you accomplish by setting all the `$_POST` to `""`?

-> You're using colons, `:`, instead of semicolons, `;`.

-> Why would you do this?